# Custom UI for Sign-In / sign-Up giving error in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We get an error when running a application with custom UI for Sign-In/Sign-Up for Azure AD B2C:

Error Details:
[[
We're having trouble signing you in.

"OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'server_error'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'AADB2C90047: The resource 'https://checkmypaystorageadb2c.blob.core.windows.net/root/unified.html' contains script errors preventing it from being loaded. Correlation ID: 94ef88b7-1df4-49e4-baca-be932f0b77bc Timestamp: 2019-09-25 11:21:22Z '. Error_Uri (may be empty): ''."
]]

custom UI :
1)Storage account Details:
[Storage account details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDfUP.png)

2) CORS settings:
[CORS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVOpn.png)

3) Set Custom Page URL in Signup-signin policy

[Custom Page url in Signup SignIn Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDQSJ.png)

4) Error Page:
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFtjK.png)

5) Test CORS:
[Test Cors Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m7hZ.png)

6) unified.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://checkmypaystoragetest.blob.core.windows.net/customsignup/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://checkmypaystoragetest.blob.core.windows.net/customsignup/favicon.png"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container unified_container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="image-center">
                <img alt="Check My Pay" class="login-logo" src="https://checkmypaystoragetest.blob.core.windows.net/customsignup/logo.png" />
              </div>
              <h3 class="text-center">Sign in with your existing account</h3>
              <div id="api" data-name="Unified">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Make sure to persist console logs when testing.

Comment: Also check the Network tab in F12 tools to see what happens when it tries to load the html.

Answer (score 0):

The pictures are not clear. But it seems a CORS error. This is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui) to customization guide. 
You need to add `PUT` as well to the allowed headers.

Answer (score 0):

We got this when blocking javascript and/or cookies in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check here

1. Try turning on `Enable JavaScript enforcing page layout` in your user
   flow under `Properties`.
2. Check the CORS setting where custom UI pages are hosted. It should point to the Allowed Origins to `https://yourb2ctenantname.b2clogin.com` and should have `GET, OPTIONS` Allowed Methods.